# 「床屋」と「髪床」の違いは何ですか？

Tags: word-choice

「**床屋**」と「**髪床**」という単語の意味は何か違いますか？
どちらが古いですか？
もし両方とも古かったら、今の時代に「美容院」以外に髪を切る場所に関してどんな単語を使ったほうが良いですか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

髪床のほうが古いですね。というか、現代あまり使わないでしょ。普段は「女性は美容院に行く」、「男性は床屋さんに行く」といいます　（ま、美容院に行く男もいるでしょうけど[image]
<sub>(source: [kolobok.us](http://smiles.kolobok.us/standart/mosking.gif))</sub>  ）

Comment: Spasibo!
どうもありがとうございます。

Comment: 散髪・散髪屋 is also widely used, although there seems to be a regional choice. 
Ref: http://www.riyo.or.jp/library/etc_kobore_01.html

Comment: 床屋 means a barbershop. 散髪 means 'to cut hair.' 散髪屋 means a shop to have your hair cut, and is an oldish expression, which I barely hear today. Both 散髪 and 散髪屋 have nothing to do with religion,Your hair grows regardless you're a Christian, Buddist, Shintoist, or Islam.

Comment: ^ 「religion(宗教)」ではなく「regional(地域的な)」とおっしゃったのですが・・・。ここ関西では、男性の行く[理容室]{りようしつ}を「散髪屋」と呼ぶ人が多いですが、関東出身の父は「床屋」と呼びます。

Comment: Interesting word 美容院. I wonder, do people sometimes mishear it as 病院?

Answer (score 3):

床屋{とこや} is a barbershop where  men frequent, while 美容院{びよういん} is a beauty salon where women frequent. 髪床{かみどこ} is an abbreviation of 髪結{かみゆ}い床{どこ}, a shop who dresses men's hair by adjusting length of hair, binding it at the back of head, and shaving the top front of the head which is called 月代{つきしろ} (tsukisiro), in the Warring States and Edo era - You can look at how Japanese men dressed their heads then in 浮世絵 - Ukiyoe. It's a counterpart to today's barbershop, but is completely obsolete today.

Answer (score 2):

「床屋」と「髪床」は、意味に違いはありませんが、「髪床」は非常に古い言葉で現在は使われません（江戸時代を連想させる言葉です）。「床屋」は現代でも使われますが、やや古い印象で、若い世代ではだんだん使わなくなってきていると思います。（「床屋」という単語は一時期放送禁止用語に入っていた<sup>†1</sup>ため、なじみが薄くなったのかもしれません。）

> 今の時代に「美容院」以外に髪を切る場所に関してどんな単語を使ったほうが良いですか？

まず法的に、日本で髪を切るところには「美容所」と「理容所」の二種類があります。本来「美容所」は主に女性向けのサービスを行う場所、「理容所」は男性向けのサービスを行う場所で、業務内容に違いがあるのですが、この区別を厳格に行う都道府県は少数で、例えば東京では事実上区別がありません<sup>†2</sup>。

そのため、特に若い世代ではまとめて「美容室」と言ったり、「床屋」と言ったりすることがあります。そもそも、普段「～に行く」という言い方をする時はどちらも使わず、「髪を切りに」とか「散髪しに」とか「ヘアカラーをしに」と言うのが一番普通だと思います。

その他の言い方：

- 「美容所」：美容院・美容室・ヘアサロン など
- 「理容所」：床屋・理髪店・散髪屋・理容室 など

---

<sup>†1 「「床屋」は、江戸時代、売春を副業としていた店があったという俗説があるため、以前はほぼ全面的に禁止となっていたが、概ね2008年（平成20年）以降、慎重に扱うべき言葉となり、内容によってはそのまま放送されることも多い。」（[ウィキペディア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E9%80%81%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E)）</sup>

<sup>†2 [安倍首相の「美容室でカット」は違法？「男の散髪」をめぐる奇妙なルール](https://www.bengo4.com/other/1146/1307/n_2781/)</sup>